# How do you use the bottom-up approach method to sort an unorder array with sublists?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

For example, if the
sorting program takes (6, 5, 9, 1, 7, 0, -3, 2) as input, it will produce a sorted list (-3, 0, 1,
2, 5, 6, 7, 9)

The order should be like this right? 8 -> 2, 2, 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1(this is output). MIPS is confusing when you branch instructions around if else statement. I got C and java, but mips...

[mergesort in C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U8XX.png)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm. I'm not sure I understand your second paragraph. Each call frame splits the input into two chunks, calls itself recursively, then when the two sublists are sorted and the call regains control, it will merge them into one list and return it to its caller. The merge works on two arrays and examines the heads of the arrays repeatedly taking the smaller element of the two heads until all elements have been removed. Note that all "arrays" are really just defined by their start and end indices all the way through the algorithm, and are not copies.

Comment: You may want to implement quicksort or insertion sort instead.  Merging is very hard to implement in-place and making copies of arrays just makes the whole thing more complex.

Comment: You need an algorithm.  You don't have to think in assembly to make an algorithm.  Find or make an algorithm in C, make sure it works, and then take it faithfully to assembly.  Your assembly questions will then be about how to do if-then-else or for-loop or recursion the same as in C rather than how to do merge of sublists in assembly.  Make the problem simpler — separate algorithm issues from assembly issues.  Assembly is so much easier when you already know what you want the code to do.